# Constructing a query depending on filter variables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Basically I need to get a bunch of data from several different tables and display it, depending upon the values of a filter (drop down box, slider and tags)

Here is my query at the moment:

```
$query_string = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users
                        JOIN user_subjects ON users.id = user_subjects.user_id
                        JOIN user_notifications ON users.id = user_notifications.user_id
                        ';

if ($subjects != 'false') {
        if (count($subjects) > 1)
        {
            // If there is more than 1 subject tag
            $query_string .= ' WHERE user_subjects.subject_id = '.$subjects[0];

            foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
                $query_string .= ' OR user_subjects.subject_id = '.$subject;
            }
        }   
        else if (count($subjects) == 1) 
        {
            // If there's only 1 subject tag, select it only
            $query_string .= " WHERE user_subjects.subject_id = ".$subjects[0];
        }
}


    if ($subscription != 'All Subscriptions')
    {
        $query_string .= ' AND users.user_plan = "'.$subscription.'"';
    }
```

So that part of the query is mostly working, but I also need to select data from another table, depending upon the filter.

the data in the extra table (named 'user_notifications') is as follows:
- user_id
- action
- entity_id
- exp_rewarded
- timestamp

So basically I need to link this table in with the user's info and get everything I need. Sorry if this isn't particularly clear. I'm still trying to figure it out myself. Let me know if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the query not working due to the OR AND issue. Use parenthesis.

```
if (count($subjects) > 1)
        {
            // If there is more than 1 subject tag
            $query_string .= ' WHERE (user_subjects.subject_id = '.$subjects[0];

            foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
                $query_string .= ' OR user_subjects.subject_id = '.$subject;
            }
             $query_string .= ')';
        }
```

Comment: Ok so that definitely seemed to help. I have another part of the query that is adding more:
"$quiz_query .= ' AND user_notifications.action = "quiz_gold" OR user_notifications.action = "quiz_silver" OR user_notifications.action = "quiz_bronze"';"

It seems to only check for the first one?

Comment: I suggest to add parenthesis eg. `WHERE (user_subjects.subject_id =1 OR user_subjects.subject_id =2) AND (users.user_plan =2) AND (user_notifications.action = "quiz_gold" OR user_notifications.action = "quiz_silver")`. Will this give you a clue?

Comment: This is all about operator precedence. OR has lower operator precedence than AND. You could check on [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: I got it working! Thanks. Now I need to do a few more things. Firstly, I need to get the total exp_rewarded. I tried putting this at the beginning: "SELECT *, SUM(user_notifications.exp_rewarded) as total_exp", but it returns unexpected results. Why would this be?

Comment: Did you run that query in the mysql? The SELECT seems fine.

Comment: Nope, just running it through php.

Comment: Suggest to run it through MYSQL first. In this way, easier to troubleshoot whether it is SQL syntax or PHP issue.